# JS Filter through exceptions

Tags: javascript

I've written like that code and it works.
Could you help to make it dynamic?

```js
function compact(arr) {
  const consts = [false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN]
  let result = arr.filter(state => state != consts[0] && state != consts[1] && state != consts[2] && state != consts[3] && state != consts[4] && state != consts[5])
  return result
}

console.log( compact([0, 1, false, 2, "", 3]) ); // => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: `state != consts[5]` will always be true, since no value is `== NaN`.

Comment: It would be a lot safer to use `!==` instead of `!=` to distinguish between the different falsy values. If you want to check if the value is `NaN` you will have to do `isNaN(value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the `filter` callback.

```js
function compact(arr) {
  const consts = [false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN]
  let result = arr.filter(state => !consts.includes(state))
  return result;
}
console.log(compact([0, 1, false, 2, "", 3]));
```

If you just want to remove the falsy values, you can directly return the current element in the callback, which will remove the element if it is not truthy. `arr.filter(Boolean)` works as well, as mentioned by [nick zoum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133418).

```js
function compact(arr) {
  return arr.filter(x => x);
}
console.log(compact([0, 1, false, 2, "", 3]));
```

Comment: or `filter(Boolean)`